# What is the use case of -f (dash f, flag f) of ssh command?

Tags: ssh

I have been confused about this `-f` option for months. What's use case of this option?

From the manpage:

```
-f      Requests ssh to go to background just before command execution.  This is useful if ssh is going to
        ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background.  This implies -n.  The
        recommended way to start X11 programs at a remote site is with something like ssh -f host xterm.
```

What does *"This is useful if ssh is going to ask for passwords or passphrases, but the user wants it in the background."*  mean exactly?  I don't understand it at all! I see no differences whether providing `-f` or not when I am going to be asked for password.

`ssh rick@1.2.3.4 "ls -l"`, `ssh -f rick@1.2.3.4 "ls -l"` makes no differences.

Could someone help and clear my doubts?

Comment: Neither of your examples are running a command, though. They're just starting a shell. Run a command (say, `sleep 10` or something that takes time) and see.

Answer (score 3):

If you try to run ssh in the background, as with

```
ssh user@host some_command &
```

ssh will be *stopped* by a `SIGTTIN` signal when it tries to read a password or passphrase from the terminal, and it will not be able to proceed further.

Notice however that `ssh -f` will not really run ssh in the *background*, because you won't see it in the job table, and you won't be able to bring back to the foreground with `fg`: the way it runs in the "background" is as if it were started with `setsid(1)`.

Comment: Thanks for the example and I didn't know that " `ssh -f` will not really run ssh in the background" .

Comment: When would you like to `ssh` to run in the background? Any common use cases? I just can't think of any conditions that I need `ssh -f`.

Comment: @Rick the way `ssh -f` runs is as with the `setsid` utility. I have used `ssh -f` when I needed to set up forwardings, etc (there's an option where `-f` won't go to the bg until the forwardings have succeeded).

Comment: `ssh -f -o ExitOnForwardFailure=yes ...`

Comment: so after that command has succesfully returned, you can use its forwadings further down in the same script, something you won't be able to do with `ssh ... &`, even if `ssh` is not asking for any password.

Comment: Well I don't know much about forwardings... Hmmm

Comment: @Rick nothing to worry about. I too didn't have to do ssh forwardings until late in my 30s